# How to find ATE in panel data when only post treatment values are available?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, treatment-effect, causalimpact

I am working on a problem for understanding the impact of a customer acquisition strategy by a company. Here, the company has run a few strategies for acquiring customers, which are online ads, billboards, referrals, organic. I am trying to estimate the ATE of the referral strategy, considering organic strategy as the control, from the data generated for these strategies.

The data have the following columns:

1. Customer ID
2. City
3. First purchase date
4. Acquisition method
5. ethnicity
6. Week after acquisition
7. Average dollars per transaction at the time point mentioned in (6)

So, we have multiple values of output for a customer over different time points. This kind of resembles a panel data. City and ethnicity are kind of time-invariant variables, and acquisition strategy is the treatment column.

But we cannot run fixed effects model here as the treatment value for a customer doesn't change over time. We cannot run DiD or synthetic control because we do not have the pre-treatment values of output. I was thinking of propensity score based approach, but for that also we don't have many variables that can influence the chances of unit getting the treatment.

How can I estimate the ATE for a treatment in this case?